# How do I keep my conditional formatting in my subform after losing focus?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a subform where a selected record controls data displayed on the main form. I'd like the selected record on the subform to be highlighted yellow via conditional formatting.

**Method 1**

Setting the conditional format to "Field Has Focus" works when the subform has focus, but the highlighting stops when clicking outside the subform.

**Method 2**

Setting the conditional format to "Expression Is" and creating a textbox in the main form equal to the subform Record ID only highlights the first record in the subform.

`[SubformID] = [Forms]![frm_MainForm]![tbSubformID]`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 is close.

Instead, use a hidden textbox on the subform. In the Form_Current event for the subform, set the .Value property equal to the ID of the currently selected record. Then, use conditional formatting to check if the value of that textbox is equal to the value of the ID field for your subform using *Expression Is*.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!